# error: file not found: FirstJavaProgram.java Usage: javac <options> <source files> use --help for a list of possible options On jdk 14.04

Tags: java, cmd, classpath

I installed jdk 14.0.2 on my window 10 OS. I set the path and JAVA_HOME variable. I also check Versions using `java -version` and `javac -version` but when I try to compile simple program using cmd it gives me the following error:

```
error: file not found: FirstJavaProgram.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: When you're launching javac, are you in the folder where FirstJavaProgram.java is located ? What are the options you used ? Please, be more precise.

Comment: @BenjaminD yes I stored FirstJavaProgram.java on Dsektop and I use `C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop>javac FirstJavaProgram.java` to run the file

Answer (score 1):

In order to successfully run `javac FirstJavaProgram.java` you must be in the same folder where the file FirstJavaProgram.java is. Check that you are in that folder when you issue the `javac` command. If you're not, change your current path in the command line with `cd path\to\the\correct\folder` where path\to\the\correct\folder is wherever you have your FirstJavaProgram.java file, and then run the `javac` command again.

Comment: yes I stored FirstJavaProgram.java on Desktop and I use `C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop>javac FirstJavaProgram.java` to run the file.

Comment: That's strange. Maybe it's an issue with the file's permissions? I assume you're logged in to your computer with the user Lenovo that's the owner of the Desktop folder where the file is, and has read/write permissions on the *.java file, so I doubt that's the case, but it's worth checking just in case.